# Filter Gravity Form Custom Post Type Select Box

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, custom-post-type, gravity-forms-plugin

We have a gravity form that uses custom functions (inside the theme's function.php) to allow folks to create a custom post type (called a “Stop").

http://hotroddingamerica.com/post-a-stop/
(it does require to be logged in- sorry)

When users create a “Stop" they are given the option to enter a contest of sorts by selecting a specific “Challenge" to tie their stop to.

The “Challenge” is also a custom post type, and when the user selects a challenge they are assigning that “Challenge Post" as a parent for their “Stop Post".

We have the form showing all the challenges via select box using this of code:

```
  $challenge_posts = get_posts("orderby=title&post_type=challenge&numberposts=999"); //&post_author=" . $current_user->ID);
```

It all works perfectly, except…

Our Challenges are only active for a specific date range. We have a custom fields:

“challenge_start_date” 
“challenge_end_date”

I need the select box to only show challenges that are current.

So my question:

How do I limit the post in this select box to only show challenges that are “active”?